# Would a long chain of inverters induce jitter?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, clock, jitter

I've recently designed a high-speed driver with the clock working at a highest frequency of 10GHz.But as the clock period becomes shorter,I've found that jitter situation too serious to be ignored.

In order to help high-frequency clock to work,I adjust the buffer fanout to be 2:3,so that means adding lots of buffers(CMOS inverters) to form a GHz clock chain(over 20x stages),(it surely seems abnormal to me at the beginning,but I just think there is no better choice),will that possibly responsible for the jitter?
[image] 
The following pic shows the clock at 7GHz. 
[image]

Comment: Show your schematic. Without it "buffer fanout" and "20 stages" are meaningless.

Comment: Reducing jitter is a filtering or conditioning operation. You would need something like a PLL.

Answer (score 4):

Identical inverters/buffers, each with independent internal KTnoise sources, will increase the time jitter by sqrt(Number inverters). [The resultant Jitter display will be Gaussian, with definite bell-curve dominant center, and very faint symmetric tails; the OP question's scope display does not show that. Hence the cause of Tj is not random noise.]

Using TimeJitter = Vnoise/SlewRate, you need to boost the slewrate and/or reduce the Vnoise.

The VDD trash, identical to all the inverters, can be a problem because that deterministic jitter simply adds........because the trash is common to all circuits.

Lets do a bit of math: assume your bandwidth is 100GigaHertz for your inverters.
Assume your Rnoise is 60 ohms (thus noise density is 1.0nanoVolts/rtHz. Assume your inverters are one set of CMOS inverters, with SlewRate of 0.5 volts/25 picoseconds. What is the jitter per stage?

Total noise (ignoring any pi/2 factors) is 1.0nVrms * sqrt(100GigaHz) = 1e-9 * 3.16e5 =3.16e-4 = 0.314 milliVolts rms.

SlewRate is 0.5v/25pS or 1v/50pS or 20Billion Volts/second or 2e+10volts/second.

Using the OhmsLaw for Jitter --- Tj = Vn/SR --- we have

$$Tj = 0.314milliVolts / 2e+10volt/second = 0.15 * 10^[-3-(+10)] = 0.15 * 0.1pS = 15femtoSec$$

By the way, the standard scale-up (drive strength) for CMOS inverters is about 3, thus 1:3:10:30:100 should be possible. If your Vt is << VDD, that ratio can be 1:5:25:125, which simulations will reveal.

---

{EDIT} Grey & Meyer discuss noise modeling. For bipolars, rbb' often dominates.
For CMOS, 1/gm gets you a very close approximation to the noise mechanism.
As Neil_K suggested, the power supply is a risk. MIC5205 has noise density of 200 nanoVolts/rtHz. ADP151 is 20 nanoVolts/rtHz. ADP7159 has 1.7nanoVolts/rtHz.

---

{EDIT #2} Consider the 200nanoVolt/rtHz noise density of MIC5205. If bandwidth of that LDO is approximately 1MegaHertz, the output noise will be 200nV * sqrt(1,000,000Hz) or 200e-9 * sqr(1e6) == 200e-9 * 1+3 = 200 microVolts rms.

Per datasheet, that TPS73201 regulator also has switching noise, internally generated. You'll need to predict the jitter caused by that. Notice there are no Gaussian Tails on your scope display.

Use the formula---- Tjitter = Vnoise/SlewRate ---- to predict the jitter.

---

{edit#3} Changed 0.314 volts to 0.314 milliVolts; result is 15femtoSec Tj

Note the PSRR of CML current-mode-logic is high, from DC to Gigahertz, if used as differential-in and differential-out. PSRR of CommonSource+Rload is zero. PSRR of CMOS inverters is 6dB.

The chosen LDO TPS73201 produces 250uV of trash at 4MHz.
[image]

Comment: Fair enough,still two questions:(1)How can I calculate the actual Rnoise?I remember Rnoise is some thermal noise with an expression like 4kTR,but where is this resistance coming from in this scenario,which seemingly not included in the simulation?(2)I find during the simulation process that as frequency gets higher,scale-up tends to shrink(Vt=0.4V,VDD=1.2V) to allow pulling up/down in a shorter period of time,or the scale up shouldn't change?

Comment: I'm not going to add my answer, yours is fairly thorough, but I will mention one further noise mechanism that bit me where I sit down when designing a low noise synthesiser. A buffer whose propagation delay is a function of rail voltage (ie all of them) will turn a noisy supply voltage into jitter. Not all LDOs are equal, the MIC5205 for instance is >20dB worse for rail noise than ADP151, and the ADP7159 is head and shoulders better than the 151. A passive RC between the LDO and the buffer can also help. Analog transistors will often be better than logic buffers for added jitter.

Comment: @Neil_K Thank you. Those 3 LDOs showed the expected effect, in that noiseFloor is 1/Iground of the servo-amplifier. Approximately. And the PSRR was poor, for the lowest Iground.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf@Neil_K Thank you both.I've used TI's TPS73201 as power supply,which claims itself to have 30μVrms low noise（10kHz-100kHz）.How can I tell if this is eligible for my design?

Comment: After chatting with local engineer, we conclude the TPS73201 is your problem.

Comment: Any status on the jitter?